# Time Range Checking

Tags: microsoft-excel

Table A

```
Agent   login    date      logout     date    working time(hrs)   Actual working time(hrs)
B     10:00 AM   12/1/14   11:00 AM   12/1/14  1:00                 0:30
A      3:00 PM   12/1/14    4:00 PM   12/1/14  1:00                 0:55
C     10:00 PM   12/1/14    1:00 AM   13/1/14  3:00                 2:00
```

Table B

```
Agent   login    date      logout     date  
B     10:30 AM  12/1/14   11:01 AM    12/1/14
B     11:00 PM  12/1/14   11:35 PM    12/1/14
B     11:40 PM  12/1/14    1:00 AM    13/1/14
A      1:59 AM  12/1/14    2:01 AM    12/1/14
A      3:00 PM  12/1/14    3:25 PM    12/1/14
A      3:30 PM  12/1/14    4:21 PM    12/1/14
C     11:00 PM  12/1/14    2:00 AM    13/1/14
```

Hello, 
Is there a way that I can calculate the actual working time in Table A by using a/few formula in MS Excel after referring to the Table B as shown above?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Unfortunately, I do not understand your example. Please describe it a little bit more

Comment: I am sorry for my ambiguous question.

Comment: I am sorry for my ambiguous question. I would like to check the actual working time for a particular agent (let say agent B from 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM).  He/She actually start to work at 10:30 AM, then log out at 11:01 AM. After that, log in and log out for the next two times. Thus, I can know that he/she work only 30 minutes. Unfortunately, this wastes the time to check one by one without formula calculation. The hardest part is various time range in table B. Thank you once again.

Comment: Why do we need Table A? Is all the information required to find out actual working time not available in Table B? Also, I'd like to know if you want to generate a report with actual working times of each of the agent on a daily basis???

Comment: For example,I inform you that I will work from 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM, then you will note it down my working time. However, you do not know I really come to work within this range. So, you will check my actual working time (table B) and you find out that I only work 30 minutes.

Comment: Yes, this is a daily basis report. However, there is a special case.For example, agent C, he/she works from 11:00 PM to 2:00 AM. The time spans to the next day midnight.

Comment: Excel can calculate past midnight, especially since you include the date..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Agent` is in cell `A1` for both tables:

In `Table B`, column `F` should have this formula filed down:
`=(E2+D2)-(C2+B2)`  (This exact formula should be in cell `F2`.)

In `Table A` the `Actual Working` formula would be:
`=SUMIF(TableB!A:A,A2,TableB!F:F)`

Comment: Not trying to hi-jack the thread, but when I put the `=(E2+D2)-(C2+B2)` formula in column `F` I get 0.021527778 in cell `F2` and `#VALUE!` in cells `F4` and `F8`. I am probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Clif, The .021527778 is the decimal representation of an Excel time code. The reason for the errors in `F4` and `F8` is because you entered the date values as MM/DD/YYYY, but the OP is from a country where it is DD/MM/YYYY. This formula evaluates perfectly well for me for all example data provided.

Comment: thanks for your answer (+1). I changed my formatting for column `F` to `[h]:mm:ss` and the times show up as hours and minutes. I converted 12/1/14 and 13/1/14 to 1/12/2014 and 1/13/2014 respectively, using `Replace`, I will have to see if there is a way to use the `Format Cells` dialog box to do that in the event that there are a large number of dates that have to be changed?

Comment: jbarker2160, Thanks for your answer. However, some of them should be considered zero hours in the table B column F. For example,second and third row for agent B in table B, they are actually out of the time range from 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM. Actually there are just few situations in table A&B. I found that it is very difficult to include all the possibilities by using nested if. Can this problem be solved by using nested if or any other better formula? After that, using <sumif> to get the answer. TQ